# Eval() alternative for variable name in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval

I've been reading about how **eval()** can be harmful. I am getting into React and I would love to learn the best practices so that I don't keep building up bad habits.
So, is there a better alternative for this?

Here's my code

```
const [paidValue, setPaidValue] = useState(props.expense.paid);
const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState(props.expense.name);

const inputBlurHandler = (e) => {
        updateExpense(id, { [e.target.name]: eval(`${e.target.name}Value`) }); 
        setSuccGreen("updatedSucc"); }
```

and bunch of inputs with names

```
<input name={"name"} type={"text"} onBlur={inputValueBlur }... />
...
```

I was using a switch statement, depending on the input name, I use the corresponding value, but I was able to replace 8 lines of code with just one using the eval()

Comment: what do you mean by `${e.target.name}Value`

Comment: [Reasons why you never should use `eval()`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-eval), especially when you rely on user's input.

Comment: what.. are you trying to do? maybe we can start from there.

Comment: @abolfazlshamsollahi I am using a template literal to get the state name by combining the name of the input and the word value (paidValue, nameValue...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to me is seems that these should not be two separate states.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(props.expense);

const inputBlurHandler = (e) => {
    updateExpense(id, { [e.target.name]: state[e.target.name] }); 
    setSuccGreen("updatedSucc"); 
}
```

Comment: This idea actually reduced my code by about 30% as I was managing each prop state on its own! And allowed me to avoid eval(). I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could just use a map (?)...

```
const [paidValue, setPaidValue] = useState(props.expense.paid);
const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState(props.expense.name);

const map = { paidValue, nameValue };

const inputBlurHandler = (e) => {
        updateExpense(id, { [e.target.name]: map[e.target.name] }); 
        setSuccGreen("updatedSucc"); }
```

However, it will return `undefined` if you either forgot to include something in the map, or the name wasn't in the map, which may or may not be worse than erroring (since `eval` would).

---

You might want to consider using a state management library as well if this gets out of control. They do it a lot better than just a map (that is really just an object using shorthand property initializer).

Comment: I find your solution really useful, I will definitely keep it in mind for future ideas. I will go with Thomas' solution as it works better for my current needs.